# Find recent date of cyclical event

Tags: sql, algorithm

Let's suppose that some event started on 1st January 2000 and is repeated every 36 hours and 45 minutes.

At this moment at my place it is 4th April 2018 18:30.

How could I calculate in SQL

- date and time of last recent happening of my event
- date and time of next future happening of my event ?

My first idea was adding my period in a loop to a start date until required date is reached but that would be very ineffective with longer time spans, I believe

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Why would you do it in SQL? Are any tables involved?

Comment: You should tag with the database that you are using.

Comment: Most 4th-generation languages have a package for handling time spans effectively (i.e. easy for the user).  For instance, in Python, you'd use `timedelta`.  Follow the basic formula in `danh`'s answer.

Comment: Yes, it would be a part of bigger SQL stored procedure

Answer (score 0):

We could parameterize an sql statement with the results of this integer math...

```
int now = current time in minutes after 1 Jan, 2000
int period = 36 * 60 + 45
int eventsBeforeNow = now / period  /* where '/' is a truncating, integer divide */
int lastEventTime = eventsBeforeNow * period
int nextEventTime = lastEventTime + period
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the answer myself. Seems to work

```
declare @minutes int,@n int,@period int
SET @period=36*60+45
select @minutes=datediff(minute,'2000-01-01 00:00:00','2018-04-04 18:30:00')
set @n=@minutes/@period 

select DATEADD(minute,@n*@period,'2000-01-01 00:00:00')
select DATEADD(minute,(@n+1)*@period,'2000-01-01 00:00:00')
```

Recent time of my example event is 2018-04-04 14:15:00.000

Next time of my example event is 2018-04-06 03:00:00.000